# What do we know about circle inscribed in a irregular hexagon?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a situation like in the picture below

[image]

I'm curious if we can compute the radius of this circle when $a$,$b$,$c$ are known.

What If length of $AB$ is also known?

What if this hexagon will be more irregular like in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Your first hexagon appears not to be a hexagon.

Comment: To find the radius, you first need to uniquely determine the hexagon. Only a triangle is uniquely determined by its sides. For larger polygons, more info is needed.

Comment: @LeeMosher It is, c-length sides are not lying on one line. I had some problems for drawing it.

Comment: @Jens what with first situation. It is hexagon which is created by two congruent trapezoids and both of them have two common points with circle which diamater is lying on AB side of trapezoid.

Comment: A trapezoid has two parallel sides. In any case, in the first situation, which is symmetric, you need to know an additional measurement, e.g. a diagonal or an angle. In general you need 9 measurements to uniquely determine a hexagon.

Comment: @Jens Thank you. Could you send me any link for this information (about 9 measurements) ?

Comment: I found the info [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51800.html). It is mentioned that it takes at least $2n-3$ numbers to determine an n-gon.

Comment: @Jens Thank you!